# (xubuntu)click on webpage file and open file with emacs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, emacs

I am using xubuntu and there are a few types of files on website that instead of downloading and saving and then opening with emacs, I would rather when the radio button choice comes up say open with emacs. I am using xubuntu with xfce, and there is no line for a command to be entered as some ubuntu editions have. In the choice of changing the opening program from mousepad to something else, it says search and allows to navigate to find a program, but I cant find emacs anywhere not in etc/ or elsewhere. So where is its executable to direct the program chooser to?

Best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a terminal and use *which* to find where in your $PATH executables are located:

```
$ which emacs
/usr/bin/emacs
$ echo $PATH
/home/redacted/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Comment: Great! I didn't really need to use the PATH variable info though.
Thanks!

Comment: @Vass: Yes, I didn't mean to say you did, was only showing the directories that which and other utilities search (of course, yours may be different from mine).  Glad I could help.

Comment: @Roger Pate, thanks again. Ah, now I see what you meant by $PATH. Geez there are so many things I have to learn.

Comment: @Roger Pate, now I get it. Whenever I need to look for a certain program I can look at the list of paths in $PATH! And I guess that $PATH's purpose is for finding user programs so they get directed to this directory? Does this go for things like a browser or command line utilities? best!

Comment: @Vass: You very rarely have to use $PATH directly as a user—except to add to it, as I've done with ~/bin in my ~/.profile, see the /home/redacted/bin part; you'd just use which to do the lookup for you (also see *man which* for -a).  Applications have to use $PATH for this lookup to work, but doing so is a very old convention that you can usually assume (anything that doesn't probably has a bug).